# Error when creating MVC Endpoints with NServiceBus

Tags: nservicebus

I just installed NServiceBus, started to go through the getting started sample, but when I tried to create a MVC endpoint as suggested here http://docs.particular.net/samples/web/ I got an unexpected exception stating that this product type is not supported by this installation, all other endpoint type work.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you don't have the ASP NET MVC 3 project type installed on your environment.
Please try installing it from http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc3.
If you have tried to install it using the Web Platform Installer Tool, be sure that you installed the right version and product (I use to make mistakes with so many similar named products).